# TCPDF blank pdf when adding svg

Tags: php, svg, tcpdf

so I was tasked with switching our code from using Imagick to tcpdf for dynamically converting svgs to pdfs.

I've ended up with following code:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../../../../../app/Mage.php';
require_once MAGENTO . '/../../../../../lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
//require_once MAGENTO . '/../../../../../lib/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php';

$app = Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$session_id = $session->getEncryptedSessionId();
$base = str_replace("/", "\/", $_POST['base']);
$b_svg = $_POST['b_svg'];
$t_svg = $_POST['t_svg'];

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('von Eicken');
$pdf->SetTitle('');
$pdf->SetSubject('');
$pdf->SetKeywords('');

$pdf->SetCellPadding(0);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (!empty($b_svg))
{
    $b_svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$_POST['b_svg'];
    $b_svg = preg_replace('#'.$base.'media#', '../../../../../media', $b_svg);
    $b_svg = urldecode($b_svg);
    $pdf->ImageSVG($file=@$b_svg, $x=0, $y=0, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
}

if (!empty($t_svg))
{
    if (!empty($b_svg)){$y=50;}
    $t_svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$_POST['t_svg'];
    $t_svg = preg_replace('#'.$base.'media#', '../../../../../media', $t_svg);
    $t_svg = urldecode($t_svg);
    $pdf->ImageSVG($file=@$t_svg, $x=0, $y, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
}
$pdf->output("./pdfs/tmp_".$session_id.".pdf", F);
echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN)."frontend/von_eicken/default/php/pdfs/temp_".$session_id.".pdf";
?>
```

I know it's a bit messy, it's in the process of conversion.

I was pleased that tcpdf seems to work really simple, however, the created pdfs don't show anything, just a single vertical line at the very top of a blank page. No error message either.
I wonder if I am missing something in my code or whether my svgs need to have some certain configuration.

I'd like to try to avoid having to plug the svgs appart to do the conversion manually, so can someone explain to me, or point me to a good tutorial, how to use the ImageSVG functionality of tcpdf properly?

Thanks a lot.

p.s. I do appreciate hints to clean up the code, too

p.p.s. Oh, btw, the third require is commented out because the file wasn't in the tcpdf package I downloaded and I figured the examples might refer to an older version. But if I really need that file, where do I get it?

Comment: First step as _always_: what does the http servers error log say?

Comment: I got no errors in any log I got access to. My webspace doesn't run as root, so if there are any higher level logs, I am not getting them. I also display php errors, but get none.

Comment: @user3154108 im also trying to export SVG to TCPDF, chart is being rendered just fine but legends text is not appearing. did u face such problem ?

Comment: Hm, not really no. Even when my custom fonts weren't available as tcpdf font yet, tcpdf put a default font up instead. Edit: But I think to have read that the setFont() method is somewhat essential to call before attempting to create a pdf, maybe you've missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake was obviously that I assumed that a new PDF object would start out with a blank page.

But it does not start out with any page at all, `$pdf->addPage()` is needed to create a page in the first place where my SVGs can be drawn on.

Frustrating little neglectances. Sorry to have bothered you all.

Comment: Don't worry, it was a reasonable question, and I'm sure others will find your answer helpful. Thanks for sharing.